# Bug in React Native app with Native Android Components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-component

I am a beginner and I have been trying to develop a React Native which uses Android native component. As a start, I created a fresh React Project. Then in the directory android/app/src/main/java/com/myApp I added all the files as given in the documentation: https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-components-android exactly as is. So my directory structure is the following and its contents are exactly as given in the documentation:

- myApp

  - CustomView.java
  - MainActivity.java
  - MainApplication.java
  - MyFragment.java
  - MyPAckage.java
  - MyViewManager.java

I then also follow the same instructions on the React Native side and put things in the .tsx files.

However, my app is not building at all. It keeps giving me the error: 'Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference'.

I have been trying in vain for the last two days to figure out why. Note that the original React Native app (without the native component changes shown above) built successfully and showed me the standard template React Native app on my Pixel 4a. But with the changes above in the Android directory (following exactly the instructions in the documentation) fails. Any suggestions/tips would be super useful!

**The code for each file is given below the picture.**

Thanks again for your attention.
Attaching a screenshot of the app error. [image]

CustomView.java:

```
package com.testapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

public class CustomView extends FrameLayout {
    public CustomView(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        // set padding and background color
        this.setPadding(16,16,16,16);
        this.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#5FD3F3"));

        // add default text view
        TextView text = new TextView(context);
        text.setText("Welcome to Android Fragments with React Native.");
        this.addView(text);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.testapp;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactActivityDelegate;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
   * rendering of the component.
   */
  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "TestApp";
  }

  /**
   * Returns the instance of the {@link ReactActivityDelegate}. Here we use a util class {@link
   * DefaultReactActivityDelegate} which allows you to easily enable Fabric and Concurrent React
   * (aka React 18) with two boolean flags.
   */
  @Override
  protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    return new DefaultReactActivityDelegate(
        this,
        getMainComponentName(),
        // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we enable the Fabric Renderer.
        DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.getFabricEnabled());
  }
}
```

MainApplication.java:

```
package com.testapp;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new DefaultReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
            packages.add(new MyPackage());
          return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean isNewArchEnabled() {
          return BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean isHermesEnabled() {
          return BuildConfig.IS_HERMES_ENABLED;
        }
      };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) {
      // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we load the native entry point for this app.
      DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.load();
    }
    ReactNativeFlipper.initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
  }
}
```

MyFragment.java:

```
package com.testapp;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

// replace with your view's import
import com.testapp.CustomView;

public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    CustomView customView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, parent, savedInstanceState);
        customView = new CustomView(this.getContext());
        return customView; // this CustomView could be any view that you want to render
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        // do any logic that should happen in an `onCreate` method, e.g:
        // customView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // do any logic that should happen in an `onPause` method
        // e.g.: customView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // do any logic that should happen in an `onResume` method
        // e.g.: customView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // do any logic that should happen in an `onDestroy` method
        // e.g.: customView.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

MyPackage.java:

```
package com.testapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MyPackage implements ReactPackage {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(@NonNull ReactApplicationContext reactApplicationContext) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        List<ViewManager> VM = new ArrayList<>();

        VM.add(new MyViewManager(reactContext));

        return VM;

        /*return Arrays.<ViewManager>asList(
                new MyViewManager(reactContext)
        );*/
    }

}
```

MyViewManager.java:

```
package com.testapp;

import android.view.Choreographer;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableArray;
import com.facebook.react.common.MapBuilder;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactProp;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactPropGroup;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewGroupManager;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext;

import java.util.Map;

public class MyViewManager extends ViewGroupManager<FrameLayout> {

    public static final String REACT_CLASS = "MyViewManager";
    public final int COMMAND_CREATE = 1;
    private int propWidth;
    private int propHeight;

    ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

    public MyViewManager(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        this.reactContext = reactContext;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return REACT_CLASS;
    }

    /**
     * Return a FrameLayout which will later hold the Fragment
     */
    @Override
    public FrameLayout createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
        return new FrameLayout(reactContext);
    }

    /**
     * Map the "create" command to an integer
     */
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Map<String, Integer> getCommandsMap() {
        return MapBuilder.of("create", COMMAND_CREATE);
    }

    /**
     * Handle "create" command (called from JS) and call createFragment method
     */
    @Override
    public void receiveCommand(
            @NonNull FrameLayout root,
            String commandId,
            @Nullable ReadableArray args
    ) {
        super.receiveCommand(root, commandId, args);
        int reactNativeViewId = args.getInt(0);
        int commandIdInt = Integer.parseInt(commandId);

        switch (commandIdInt) {
            case COMMAND_CREATE:
                createFragment(root, reactNativeViewId);
                break;
            default: {}
        }
    }

    @ReactPropGroup(names = {"width", "height"}, customType = "Style")
    public void setStyle(FrameLayout view, int index, Integer value) {
        if (index == 0) {
            propWidth = value;
        }

        if (index == 1) {
            propHeight = value;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Replace your React Native view with a custom fragment
     */
    public void createFragment(FrameLayout root, int reactNativeViewId) {
        ViewGroup parentView = (ViewGroup) root.findViewById(reactNativeViewId);
        setupLayout(parentView);

        final MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
        FragmentActivity activity = (FragmentActivity) reactContext.getCurrentActivity();
        activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(reactNativeViewId, myFragment, String.valueOf(reactNativeViewId))
                .commit();
    }

    public void setupLayout(View view) {
        Choreographer.getInstance().postFrameCallback(new Choreographer.FrameCallback() {
            @Override
            public void doFrame(long frameTimeNanos) {
                manuallyLayoutChildren(view);
                view.getViewTreeObserver().dispatchOnGlobalLayout();
                Choreographer.getInstance().postFrameCallback(this);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Layout all children properly
     */
    public void manuallyLayoutChildren(View view) {
        // propWidth and propHeight coming from react-native props
        int width = propWidth;
        int height = propHeight;

        view.measure(
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));

        view.layout(0, 0, width, height);
    }
}
```

App.tsx:

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import {
  PixelRatio,
  UIManager,
  findNodeHandle,
} from 'react-native';

import {MyViewManager} from './MyViewManager';

const createFragment = viewId =>
  UIManager.dispatchViewManagerCommand(
    viewId,
    // we are calling the 'create' command
    UIManager.MyViewManager.Commands.create.toString(),
    [viewId],
  );

const App = () => {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const viewId = findNodeHandle(ref.current);
    createFragment(viewId);
  }, []);

  return (
    <MyViewManager
      style={{
        // converts dpi to px, provide desired height
        height: PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(200),
        // converts dpi to px, provide desired width
        width: PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(200),
      }}
      ref={ref}
    />
  );
};

export default App;
```

MyViewManager.tsx:

```
import {requireNativeComponent} from 'react-native';

export const MyViewManager =
  requireNativeComponent('MyViewManager');
```

Comment: Wasn't my vote, but documentation changes, so you should make the code part of your question.

Comment: @Abe Thanks! This helps and I added the code as you suggested. Now that it has a downvote, not sure how many people will actually see it and respond.

Comment: I was able to solve this. The reason for this error was that the "MyPackage.java" file forced me to add the "createNativeModules" method and return a NULL otherwise it would not build. But then at run time, even if I was using the native component via ```requireNativeComponent``` and registereing everything correctly, the "createNativeModules" was called which was returning null and giving error. So just by removing "return null" and replacing it with "return Arrays.<NativeModule>asList();" did the job and "createViewManagers" was called correctly. Hope this helps someone.